# How to use dependency injection one one class needs to use a constructor with some primitive values?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

When in the constructor I pass interfaces that are declared as dependencies being injected, I don't have problems in this case.

For example something like this:

```
class MyMainClass : IMainClass
{
    public MyMainClass(ISecondClass paramSecondClass)
    {
        _secondClass = paramSecondClass;
    }
}

class MySecondClass : ISecondClass
{
    public MySecondClass(IThirdClass paramThirdClass)
    {
        _thirdClass = paramThirdClass;
    }
}

class MyThirdClass : IThirdClass
{
    publicThirdClass(){}
}
```

And this is how I would declare the dependency injection:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMainClass, MyMainClass>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecondClass, MySecondClass>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IThirdClass, MyThirdClass>();
```

However, suppose that the second class needs some primitive value, like an int. Then the code would be this:

```
class MyMainClass : IMainClass
{
    public MyMainClass(ISecondClass paramSecondClass, int paramMyIintparameter)
    {
        _secondClass = paramSecondClass;
    }
}
```

How should I declare the dependency injection? Because the int parameter it would be different in each case, it is a value that I will get from a configuration file, and this value is not set at first, it is null until the user set it.

Anyway, it is a primitive value, so I could register it as dependency injection.

In this case, how should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: It is already solved by the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options)

Comment: When you say "configuration file" do you actually mean "user settings"? I don't get what you mean by "it is null until the user set it" if you actually mean application configuration.